# Смещение при overflow: hidden

Tags: css

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/ksLpx2ra/

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.a {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<span>Текст</span>
<div>
  <span class = "a">Длинный текст</span>
</div>
```

Как избежать смещения элемента вниз? Вкратце: есть некоторый элемент с текстом и label, располагающийся слева от него. Если ставлю `overflow:hidden`, чтобы текст обрезался, то label смещается вниз.

Answer (score 3):

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
span {
    border: 1px solid black; float: left; margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}
.a {
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ksLpx2ra/3/ вот так?

Comment: Плохой способ. Лучше уж inline-block вместо float'а, но всё равно это не по вопросу, если нужно разместить эту штуковину внутри текста.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ksLpx2ra/4/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ksLpx2ra/2/

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.a {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<span>Текст</span>
<span class="a">Длинный текст</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ksLpx2ra/1/

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.a {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<span>Текст</span>
<div>
  <span class = "a">Длинный текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Там все равно на пиксель или 2 смещение есть из-за `display: block;` кажется.

Comment: @Visman, там не смещение, а разная высота. Второй на пиксель выше.